# How to extract name from signature in Outlook mails?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

My project is to extract the details ("Conversation Id", "Date Created", "Sender", "Sender's Name", "Sender's e-mail", "Subject", "To", "Recipients", "Entry ID") of a email items from selected Outlook folder (ex: ABC Services) and create an Excel database. I have successfully extracted the same to Excel spreadsheet.

I am facing a problem in fetching the name from the signature from each of the email items.

My team on daily basis checks the mail from an Outlook folder (ex: ABC Services) and replies with common sender mail ID (ex: ABC@xxx.com) with their respective signatures (varies according to sender ex: Vinay MG, Povel A, James Car etc.) in email body.

I want to extract the sender name from the signature. I came to know about "Suggestedsigner" from MS office site, but didn't understand much. Also I searched many sites, but no success.

My email flows as below,

> [..... ..... EMail BODY... .... ... ]
>   Regards,
>   Vinay M G | ABC Services | EFG Team
>   XXX Company, Location
>   Mob: xx-xxxxx xxxxx

I want to extract name (Vinay M G) from the signature.

Comment: Can you post example on how the signature looks like? you may also wanna post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text can be parsed out of the body.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub parseBodyForText()

    ' Test this sample code in Outlook not Excel

    ' Where mail contains a line in this format
    '  name | ABC Services | EFG Team

    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim bodyLines() As String
    Dim namelineWords() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Open applicable mail
    Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    If myItem.Class = olMail Then

        bodyLines = Split(myItem.Body, vbCrLf)

        For i = LBound(bodyLines) To UBound(bodyLines)

            ' Attempt to determine the applicable line

            'If Right(bodyLines(i), 10) = "| EFG Team" Then
            ' or
            'If InStr(bodyLines(i), "| ABC Services |") Then

            ' If the above strings are not always present.
            ' Perhaps search for the "|"
            ' Increases chance of false positives
            If InStr(bodyLines(i), " | ") Then

                Debug.Print "nameline: " & bodyLines(i)

                namelineWords = Split(bodyLines(i), "|")
                Debug.Print "first element of namelineWords array: " & namelineWords(0)

                ' Assumes no false positives
                Exit For

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Niton, You are genius!! and thanks a lot for your response and greatly appreciated :) Sorry for late reply, meanwhile i created  vb script to fetch the signature. Hence i couldn't check this post again. But, my code was taking more time to fetch signatures from email body. You have simplified the solution and now it is taking very less time for signature extraction. thanks again :)